# One of my variables in my simple calculator says that it is not being initialized. Why?

Tags: c++

I am a noob to C++, and as a part of homework I had to create a simple calculator with four functions within C++. I have done this and it works, however, I am now trying to loop it so that a user can have infinite attempts at using it, however, I am having struggles. Basically, when I run my program and tell the program which operation I'd like to use, it tells me that my variable "sum" is not being initialized. Im not quite sure what this is, or how to fix it. Any ideas? Here is my code -

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() 
{

    while (true)
    {
        int num1, num2, r;
        double sum;

        cout << "Enter a number\n";
        cin >> num1;

        cout << "Enter another number\n";
        cin >> num2;

        cout << "Please enter an operator (+ , * , /, - or End)\n";
        cin >> r;
        if (r == 'End') break;
        if (r == '+') sum = num1 + num2;
        if (r == '-') sum = num1 - num2;
        if (r == '*') sum = num1 * num2;
        if (r == '/') sum = num1 / num2;

        cout << r;
        cout << "The answer is \n" << sum << endl;
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: What will be the value of `sum` if the user enters something else than the 5 options you test for? :)

Comment: Reading into an `int` and expecting formatting ASCII input is wrong, as is expecting `'End'` to be a valid character.

Answer (score 1):

If the user enters 'a' as operator for example (something else than the valid choices), `sum` is never assigned a value, but `sum` is printed.

Comment: so what exactly do I need to do ? Im completely noob at C++.

Comment: Which book are you using, @xKetjow? Surely it explains this?

Comment: im not doing any books, it's one of my units in college, software design and development. we get taught the theory behind programming etc, but not actual programming.

Comment: @xKetjow: Learn from a book. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Answer (score 0):

The compiler says that you are trying to use an unintialized variable, `sum`.

If you think you initialize it, think again: You only assign a value if `r` is `+`, `-`, `*` or `/`. But what if `r` is `a`? <sub>`'End'` is not a character, and thus invalid</sub>

Then `sum` is never initialized/has a value, and so the compiler complains.

Comment: In none of those cases is `sum` initialised. Only assigned to.

Comment: yeah I get that, what exactly do I put into my code for this ?

Comment: @Light Even if the variable was never initialized in the first place? I always thought that, thanks :)

Comment: @Rakete1111: I _think_ old C "street talk" used "initialised" the way you did, but that's not the way the C++ standard or modern C++ "street talk" uses it.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, the variable `sum` remains uninitialized if the user enters an invalid choice for `r`. Just set `double sum=0;` and you're good to go.

In addition, `'End'` is not a char, so you can't compare it to r. You'll have to use some other option for ending.

Comment: True. It should be a char

Comment: I did the double sum=0 thing and it got rid of that problem :> What should be a char ?

Comment: Variable r should be a char, not an int. And change 'End' to a single character, say, 'E'

Comment: So i changed it, and it works. When I press E it closes so all gud. One more thing, im not sure how  to loop it so that the user can enter more than one equation without having to close the program over and over. I have a loop in there, but it doesnt seem to work.

Comment: Your loop doesn't work because you've put return 0 within the body of the loop. Shift it outside to just before the last curly brace } and the loop should work.